# How to apply position transformation

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

How do I apply the drawing position in the world via shaders?

My vertex shader looks like this:

```
in vec2 position;

uniform mat4x4 model;
uniform mat4x4 view;
uniform mat4x4 projection;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Where `position` is the positions of the vertexes of the triangles.

I'm binding the matrices as follows.

*view*:

```
glm::mat4x4 view = glm::lookAt(
                    glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.2f, 1.2f),    // camera position
                    glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),    // camera target
                    glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));   // camera up axis
GLint view_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "view");
glUniformMatrix4fv(view_uniform, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
```

*projection*:

```
glm::mat4x4 projection = glm::perspective(80.0f, 640.0f/480.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
GLint projection_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "projection");
glUniformMatrix4fv(projection_uniform, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
```

*model transformation*:

```
glm::mat4x4 model;
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
model = glm::rotate(model, static_cast<float>((glm::sin(currenttime)) * 360.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
GLint trans_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "model");
glUniformMatrix4fv(trans_uniform, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
```

So this way I have to compute the position transformation each frame on the CPU. Is this the recommended way or is there a better one?

Comment: Given your positions are in X and Y, shouldn't the up vector be X or Y (possibly 0,1,0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So this way I have to compute the position transformation each frame on the CPU. Is this the recommended way or is there a better one?

Yes. Calculating a new transform once for a mesh on the CPU and then applying it to all vertices inside the mesh inside the vertex shader is not going to be a very slow operation and needs to be done every frame.

Comment: If the transform remains the same each frame, you could possibly cache it. Eg, store a dirty flag on each objects local transform and update its world transform just before drawing. You could also pre-multiply the view and model matrices before passing them in. If you don't require the eye-space position in the shader you could premultiply the lot - producing a "model-view-projection" matrix so there's no matrix multiplies in the vertex shader (a little less expensive overall).

Answer (score 2):

In the `render()` method you usually do the following things

- create matrix for camera (once per frame usually)
- for each object in the scene:

  - create transformation (position) matrix
  - draw object

projection matrix can be created once per `windowResize`, or when creating matrix for camera.

Answer: **Your code is good**, it is a basic way to draw/update objects.

You could go into some framework/system that manages it automatically. You should not care (right now) about the performance of those matrix creation procedures... it is very fast. Drawing is more problematic.

as *jozxyqk* wrote in one comment, you can create `ModelViewProjMatrix` and send one combined matrix instead of three different one.